# Warning: Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js latest version for making my blog website, don't know why show me error, when I'm trying to make my form then show me error like this:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. 
Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

[image]

I'm tried below code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { APP_NAME } from "../config";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
} from "reactstrap";

const Header = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
        <Link href="/">
          <NavbarBrand className="font-weight-bold">{APP_NAME}</NavbarBrand>
        </Link>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav className="m-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <Link href="/signup">
                <NavLink style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Signup</NavLink>
              </Link>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <Link href="/signin">
                <NavLink style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Signin</NavLink>
              </Link>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

please give me your valuable suggestion.

Comment: The error message suggests React.forwardRef might be the solution. Have you considered that? Have you looked up how it works?

Comment: I don't know where I should use React.forwordRef, can you help me!

Comment: Since the error message doesn't even refer to the code you've shared: no.

Comment: sorry, now i have updated my code, please let me know where is error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the official documentation: [if-the-child-is-a-function-component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component) shows the right way when you wrap a custom function component within `Link`.

1. Add `passHref` attribute in `Link`.
2. Wrap your custom function component with `React.forwardRef`.

However, the `NavbarBrand` is not a component which you can manipulate. You can create a custom component to wrap `NavbarBrand`. It probably like

```
const CustomNavbarBrand = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, href }, ref) => {
  return (
    <NavbarBrand href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      Click Me
    </NavbarBrand>
  )
})

<Link href="/" passHref>
  <CustomNavbarBrand>{APP_NAME}</CustomNavbarBrand>
</Link>
```

Check the valid property which can be passed to `NavbarBrand` since I haven't use the `reactstrap` before.

Comment: Is there a typescript version for this?

Answer (score 46):

The easiest solution may be to wrap your NavLink with a native html element. In your case:

```
<Link href="/signup" passHref>
  <a>
    <NavLink style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Signup</NavLink>
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Where is the export NavLink?

Comment: from "reactstrap"

Answer (score 8):

Solution :

1. **Wrapp with anchor tag** (a tag)
2. use **passHref** attribute

```html
<Link href='/' passHref>
  <a>
    <Image src='logo.png' width="50px" height="50px" />
  </a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
<Link href="/">
      <div className="navbar-brand">
        <a>{APP_NAME}</a>
      </div>
    </Link>
```

Instead of using the NavbarBrand component I just added the class navbar-brand

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the child component in an `a` (anchor) tag resolved my issue.

Steps to reproduce :

1. Wrap around a component with the `Link` tag from [Next JS](https://nextjs.org/)

import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'

```
<Link href="/">
<Image  width="100%"
       height="100%"
       src="/logo.png"
       alt="Blitztech Electronics Logo" />
<Link>
```

Solution :

1. passing the 'important' `passHref` attribute
2. Wrapping the entire children in a `a` tag

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to solve this issue: whenever you are going to add a child tag under Link tag, such as an Image tag, just wrap them under a div or a tag. Here is the example:

```
  <Link href="/">
              <div>
                <Image
                  src={Logo}
                  alt={TagName.COMPANY_NAME}
                  width={80}
                  height={80}
                  onClick={handleClicked}
                />
              </div>
   </Link>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just Wrap it in anchor tag. it will work fine.

```
<Link href="/">
      <a>{APP_NAME}</a>
</Link>
```