# How to handle: Check the render method of `ForwardRef`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this Next.js / React component:

```js
const AppBarContent = (props: Props) => {
    // ** Props
    const {
        horizontalAppBarContent: userHorizontalAppBarContent,
        horizontalAppBarBranding: userHorizontalAppBarBranding,
    } = props

    // ** Hooks
    const theme = useTheme()

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                width: '100%',
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
        >
            {userHorizontalAppBarBranding ? (
                userHorizontalAppBarBranding(props)
            ) : (
                <Link href="/">
                    <Image src={'/images/logo.svg'} width={48} height={48} />
                </Link>
            )}
```

Got this warning:

> next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? Check the render method of `ForwardRef`.

If I put `const AppBarContent = React.forwardRef((props: Props, ref) => {` around component as one suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66423250/239219

I still get the error, but if I but  between  and  warning disappear.

```js
<Link href="/">
<a>
<Image src={'/images/logo.svg'} width={48} height={48} />
</a>
</Link>
```

what can I do. I think my solution is not based on Next.js doc, it is a shortcut. But the proper solution does not work. Why?

---

```js
    return (
        <HorizontalLayoutWrapper className="layout-wrapper">
            {/* Navbar (or AppBar) and Navigation Menu Wrapper */}
            <AppBar
                color="default"
                elevation={skin === 'bordered' ? 0 : 3}
                className="layout-navbar-and-nav-container"
                position={appBar === 'fixed' ? 'sticky' : 'static'}
                
            >
                {/* Navbar / AppBar */}
                <div className="layout-navbar">
                    <div className="navbar-content-container">
                        <AppBarContent
```

Comment: How do you use `AppBarContent` component? How and where?

Comment: pasted down there

Comment: Wrapping the `Link` with an `<a>` is the right solution here.